# How to fetch MAC address of remote machine from docker container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-container

I am using `python:3.6-alpine` docker container.
I have a network service which finds MAC address of a supplied ip address.
To find mac address of given remote machine say `host=10.11.15.100` i'm using
below python3 script.

```
import getmac 
mac_address = getmac.get_mac_address(ip=host)
```

When I run this script locally it gives proper mac address of provided host.
But when I run it in docker container it gives `None`.
Note:- I am able to ping given host from docker container but unable to get mac address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to ping given remote machine from docker container but unable to get the mac address that means either

1. MAC address is not available in the routing table
2. The host network interface is not available inside a Docker container.

For #1 case you can ping the machine which can add MAC address of that machine in the routing table.
For #2 case you can add a host network interface to Docker container.
eg. `docker run --network="host" -it network_service:latest`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to get the MacAddress of your container

```
docker container inspect -f {{.NetworkSettings.MacAddress}} container-id
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. Actually I am looking for remote machine/LAN machine address from docker container. Let's say I have network service which is used to find mac address of given ip address of remote machines.